# How would I count the number of processing cores/threads a program would use | C#

Tags: c#

I would like to have my program look at another application and count the number of cores/threads it would use with unlimited resources. This is to determine if an application is using more than one core or not.

I have looked into `System.Diagnostics` and threads does not appear to count processing threads. Neither does affinity help because a user can change this.

How would I get like an Int that had the max number of cores say chrome could use?

Comment: You might find that profiling your code would be helpful, however this question is too broad.

Comment: You want to determine how many cores/threads an application would use with unlimited resources in order to determine if that application is using more than one core? That seems like looking at your gas tank capacity to find out if you're currently driving to Taco Bell.

Comment: and unclear. what is this "another application"? the numbers of cores used depends on so many factors and can vary over time, and is subject to change with OS versions and OS settings, what do you really need to achieve?

Comment: Say i wanted to find the most cores chrome would use or how many cores it was built to utilize. I know most applications today are mutli threaded/cores but some still are not and I want to find the most cores an app would use.

Comment: Chrome is special because its engine launches a *process* per tab, so this makes the definition of your metric even more complicated. Either way this probably cannot be done by measuring. You never know which code paths of the measured app you'd have to trigger to see utilization of multiple cores without having the source code. And it depends on the OS too. Assigning executable code to a logical or physical cpu core is a scheduling task of the kernel, not a property of the user code.

Comment: Even within a single process, some things will be parallelizable but others by nature will be difficult or impossible to perform in parallel. Furthermore, some things may be technically parallelizable but in practice there would be so many locks required that any potential benefit is lost. Furthermore (again), the framework itself may take code that is capable of running in parallel but run it all on one (or only a few) threads.

Comment: I guess another way of saying this is how could I determine the number of cores/threads a program was coded to use.

Comment: the number of cores is a property of the runtime environment. applications like browsers (which you mentioned as an example) are never coded to use with a certain number of cores. Their programming environments and runtime libraries all provide sufficient hardware abstraction to accomodate for anything a compatible hardware can offer, from one core upwards. the potential number of threads spawned is not something that developers explicitely specify in a way it could become a deterministic property of an executable. A program can be single-threaded or multi-threaded. independently from cores.